# Show custom error page for status codes greater than 599

Tags: java, http, struts

We use custom http status codes in our struts 1.1 app. They are defined in web.xml under the `<error-page>` definitions. The problem I'm having is that our error page (also defined in web.xml for those status codes) isn't showing for these status codes. It will, however, show for normal 400 and 500 status codes. Is there something special I need to do to get custom http status codes to call our custom error page? Currently I'm using

```
response.sendError(601, "custom message")
```

to trigger the error status but it always goes to the default tomcat error page. I can show more code if needed.

here is the error page definition:

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>601</error-code>
   <location>/jsp/Error.jsp?errorCode=601</location>
</error-page>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your <error-page> definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your error-page definition in a sample webapp's web.xml works fine with Tomcat 5.0.28 and Struts 1.1 too. Just checked.
As a workaround you can set the error code/msg in the request always forward to the error page

Comment: did you use response.sendError() to get it to resond with an error status?
How would i set the error code in the request to always forward to the error page?

Comment: ok, I think I've eliminated it having to do with the kind of status code or the error page definition. I got it to work with a normal request and forcing an error status with response.sendError(). I think the problem has to do with the specific type of situation in which I'm trying to respond with an error status. I'm going to accept your answer and post another question specific to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Status codes beyond 599 are not allowed in HTTP. So: don't.

Comment: That may be the case, but tomcat still shows the correct status code when it is set by resonse.sendError(). My question is why it wouldn't use my custom error page not if it's allowed by http.

Comment: Which Tomcat version do you use? Do you have some more information like action-mappings? With Tomcat 7.0.29 and Struts 1.3.10 there's no problem forwarding to an error page by setting a custom error code in the action class. I assume you use the same error.jsp for the other errors only the parameter is different.

Comment: Sadly we use Tomcat 5.0.28. Yes, we use the same Error.jsp for every status code and all exceptions with a different parameter for each.